# Demonstration of the variance on a $C_{\ell}$ : can't make appear into demonstration a term "$-1$"

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, covariance, wick-theorem

Regardings the definition of $C_{\ell}$ on a survey, we measure all the $2 \ell+1$ coefficients. We are thus led to define an estimator of the observed power spectrum
$$
\hat{C}_{\ell}=\frac{1}{2 \ell+1} \sum_{m}\left|a_{\ell m}\right|^{2}\quad(1)
$$
with the property $\left\langle\hat{C}_{\ell}\right\rangle=C_{\ell}$. Note that in Eq$(1)$ the ensemble average does not appear: we are forced to measure $C_{\ell}$ only with a limited number of values. This induces an intrinsic source of inaccuracy due to replacing the true variance $C_{\ell}$ with the observed power $\hat{C}_{\ell}$ (i.e., by replacing the ensemble average with the average over directions). This effect is known as cosmic variance.

Below the demonstration of the variance : **I can't manage to make appear the first term "$-1$" below :**
\begin{aligned}
\left\langle\left(\frac{\hat{C}_{\ell}-C_{\ell}}{C_{\ell}}\right)^{2}\right\rangle &=-1+\frac{1}{(2 \ell+1)^{2} C_{\ell}^{2}} \sum_{m m^{\prime}}\left\langle a_{\ell m} a_{\ell m}^{*} a_{\ell m^{\prime}} a_{\ell m^{\prime}}^{*}\right\rangle \\
&=-1+\frac{1}{(2 \ell+1)^{2} C_{\ell}^{2}}\left[\sum_{m}\left\langle a_{\ell m} a_{\ell m}^{*} a_{\ell m} a_{\ell m}^{*}\right\rangle+\sum_{m, m^{\prime} \neq m}\left\langle a_{\ell m} a_{\ell m}^{*} a_{\ell m^{\prime}} a_{\ell m^{\prime}}^{*}\right\rangle\right]\quad(2)\\
&=-1+\frac{1}{(2 \ell+1)^{2} C_{\ell}^{2}}\left(3 C_{\ell}^{2}(2 \ell+1)+2 \ell C_{\ell}^{2}(2 \ell+1)\right) \\
&=\frac{2}{2 \ell+1}
\end{aligned}
where the third equality follows from Wick's theorem.

If someone could help me to make appear this term "$-1$" present yet at the first line of demonstration lines $(2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty standard property of variances:
$$
\left\langle\left(\frac{\hat{C}-C}{C}\right)^2\right\rangle
=
\frac{1}{C^2}\left\langle\hat{C}^2-2\hat{C}C+C^2\right\rangle
=
\frac{1}{C^2}\left\langle\hat{C}^2\right\rangle
-\frac{1}{C^2}\left\langle2\hat{C}C\right\rangle
+\frac{1}{C^2}\left\langle C^2\right\rangle\,,
$$
which then simplifies to
$$
\frac{\langle\hat{C}^2\rangle}{C^2}
-2\frac{1}{C}\langle\hat{C}\rangle
+\frac{C^2}{C^2}
=
\frac{\langle\hat{C}^2\rangle}{C^2}
-2\frac{C}{C}
+1
=\frac{\langle\hat{C}^2\rangle}{C^2} -1\,,
$$
since $\langle \hat{C}\rangle=C$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Just a detail : how to make go out the factor $$\langle\dfrac{1}{C}\rangle$$ from the expectation  $$\left\langle\dfrac{1}{C}\right\rangle$$ : is it assimilate to a constant a priori ? Regards.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you're asking why we can pull out factors of $2$, $C$, and $1/C^2$ from the expectation, then that's just a property of expected values, that you can pull out constants.  The average of (5 * (heights of people in Laos)) is the same as 5*(average of heights of people in Laos).

Comment: ok, thanks a lot !